# ErrorvCS1955 - Non-invocable member '_Default.ResultsArray' cannot be used like a method. How do I fix this?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (var index = 0; index <= ResultsSaveIndex - 1; index++)
        sb.AppendLine (ResultsArray(index));
    TextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

The error is happening to the (ResultsArray(index).

Comment: I suspect you just meant to use `[]` instead of `()`, e.g. `sb.AppendLine(ResultsArray[index]);`

Comment: Note that a more idiomatic `for` loop would be `for (var index = 0; index < ResultsSaveIndex; index++)`... or more simply, use a `foreach` loop or just a single call to `string.Join`: `TextBox1.Text = string.Join("", ResultsArray.Take(ResultsSaveIndex));`